# About the word Akagami

Tags: words, pronunciation, rendaku

So my question is very simple. I know that Akagami means red hair but isn't hair in japanese named "kami"? I want to understand why it is akagami instead of akakami. Hope this question doesn't sound stupid.

Comment: Your question will probably be closed as a duplicate, but please don't take that as any indication that you are wrong to ask this.  It's a good question, and not stupid.  :)  The link naruto added above talks about this phenomenon.  It's technically called 連濁 (_rendaku_), which refers to the way the first consonant in a word becomes voiced when the word is the second part of a compound.  Happy learning!